How to configure InstallPrivileges for WiX v4?
I'm using an immediate Custom Action in my MSI installer that requires admin rights but also needs to run under the user context. When I run the installer without admin privileges, I get an 'Access Denied' exception in the Custom Action. However, running the installer from an elevated PowerShell session resolves the issue.
Is there a way to request or enforce admin privileges when the user starts the MSI file?
This answer seems to address my issue, however, I haven't been able to find a way to configure InstallPrivileges for WiX v4.

Immediate CustomActions are not elevated. You need a deferred CustomAction that is not impersonated to get system privileges.

Thank you for your reply! In my case, I use a deferred custom action with impersonation, as I need to operate in the current user's context. Specifically, I am registering a task in the Windows Task Scheduler (which requires admin rights); however, I am configuring the task to be triggered on the current user's logon, so this action needs to run with impersonation.
